# Access VBA: How to press OK?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this code:

```
Private Sub _Click()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryA", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryB", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenQuery "queryC", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.Close acForm, "formA", acSaveNo
End Sub
```

When I execute it a lot of message boxes appear.
Is there a command that will press OK for every message box?

Comment: What do the message boxes say?

Comment: There is no generic "command" that will press OK in every message box. As far as a custom way to do so, it's possible, but you haven't given any information about the message boxes that would let us tell you how. "A lot of message boxes appear" is not a specific enough problem description to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this.

The first - use `SetWarnings`:

Before your `OpenQuery`s, insert the line:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

and after the `OpenQuery`s, insert the line:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

This will prevent most warning and confirmation messages from appearing at all.

The second option - replace `DoCmd.OpenQuery` with `Database.Execute`:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "queryA"
CurrentDB.Execute "queryB"
CurrentDB.Execute "queryC"
```

This will execute action queries without confirmation.  It also has an additional advantage: If you add the `dbFailOnError` constant as the second parameter, you can get VBA to throw an error if any part of your query does not do what it is supposed to do - a situation that OpenQuery ignores.  For example, if you are running an `Update` query and it is making several changes including an invalid change to one field due to an incompatible datatype, `OpenQuery` could result in an inconsistent update while `Execute` would result in an error and no changes:

```
CurrentDB.Execute "queryA", dbFailOnError
```

There is no easy way to "press OK" on all the messages, but you can stop them from appearing at all.

Comment: @etamar211: Good answer, but just a caveat.  Code an error handler into your sub and make sure no matter what, you run DoCmd.SetWarnings True before you exit, even on error. It is an application-wide setting and without an error handler, if something happens in the body of that code and it doesn't run, you won't be receiving those message boxes ever unless you run SetWarnings again manually.